# Query with multiple, optional where conditions (clauses) in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I search/filter by multiple parameters that are each optional in Rails 3.2?  With the setup below, I am currently getting the following error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
undefined method `paginate' for nil:NilClass

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:50:in `index'
```

Here is the index action in my contacts_controller:

```
def index
  city = params[:city]
  state = params[:state]
  zip = params[:zip]
  @contacts = Contact.search(city,state,zip).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => items_per_page)
end
```

And here is the search method in my Contact model:

```
def self.search(city, state, zip)
  joins(:profile => :addresses)
  .where("city like ?", "%#{city}%") unless city.blank?
  .where("state = ?", state) unless state.blank?
  .where("zip like ?", "%#{zip}%") unless zip.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to return more explicitely, e.g. like that:

```
def self.search(city, state, zip)
  query_obj = joins(:profile => :addresses)
  query_obj = query_obj.where("city like ?", "%#{city}%") unless city.blank?
  query_obj = query_obj.where("state = ?", state) unless state.blank?
  query_obj = query_obj.where("zip like ?", "%#{zip}%") unless zip.blank?

  query_obj
end
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.search(city, state, zip)
  conditions = {:"city like %?%" => city, :state => state, :"zip like %?%" => zip}
  conditions.delete_if {|key,val| val.blank? }
  self.joins(:profile => :addresses)
  .where(conditions)
end
```

and your function Contact.search(city,state,zip) returns **nil** that's why it gives error of nil.paginate.